# Ubuntu Bundler HTTPError

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. When I installed Ruby and gems, everything worked fine for a while, but then from one point on Bundler started showing errors:

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.
Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API
Fetching full source index from http://rubygems.org/
```

Then it stays like that until some moment in the space-time continuum. Before it used to bundle gems in an extremely low speed, but now it just doesn't do anything.

I'm pretty newbish when it comes to system administration, pinging, proxies etc. but I tried everything I could find on the internet, using `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS`, checking if my terminal correctly resolves the URL, reinstalling bundler... even [logging out and back in](https://superuser.com/questions/432416/websites-resolving-in-browser-but-not-resolving-in-cli-can-ping-ip-but-not-doma).

Any suggestions on how I should start debugging this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue with dependency API is because that part of RubyGems server is currently down. Take a look at http://status.rubygems.org/

[image: Image from RubyGems status server as of 9PM MDT]

Comment: Not much of a relief in that it is still down!  Seems a pretty major single point of failure?

Comment: Yup. The rubygems team is working hard to address all the issues though; recently they had a google hangout session with all the devs involved, and those who wanted to help out. More details here: https://twitter.com/qrush/status/259477998246440960

Comment: In the meantime, use `source "http://bundler-api.herokuapp.com"` in your Gemfile.